# Method to convert String to int array

Tags: java, array, rags-to-riches

I was working on a suggestion for [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75855/a-way-to-handle-integer-input) question, but the method, I would've suggested the OP do something similar to, seems a bit convoluted.

It's supposed to take a String input and return an array of only the integers deliminated by spaces. It does this correctly, but It feels like I may be doing some unnecessary things or there's a more succinct way to do this, such as with regex.

```
public static int[] getIntegers(String s) {
    int[] result;
    ArrayList<Integer> helper = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == ' ' ^ i == s.length() - 1) {
            if (i == s.length() - 1) { sb.append(s.charAt(i)); }
            if (sb.toString().length() > 0) {
                try { helper.add(Integer.parseInt(sb.toString()));
                } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        // Ignore non-integers
                }
                sb.setLength(0);
                continue;
            }
        }
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }

    result = new int[helper.size()];
    int i = 0;

    for (Integer n : helper) {
        result[i++] = n;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thinking this may be more appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to tag this with `rags-to-riches` too? Not sure the extent of the makeover here. :D

Comment: I personally wouldn't be opposed. Not just one but two superior methods!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ohhhh.... XOR logic on booleans in Java ..... how esoteric:

> ```
> if (s.charAt(i) == ' ' ^ i == s.length() - 1) {
> ```

That should be removed "just because". It's hard to understand, the logic is inverted, and it is not short-circuit, so it tests the `i == s.length() - 1` even when `s.charAt(i) == ' '`

I think what you have is an inverted logic problem. You are looking for all the digits in the input, when, instead, you should be looking for not-digits....

The supporting logic, using StringBuilders, etc. is not a bad idea.... but, have you considered a regular-expression?

```
String[] digitwords = input.split("\\D+");
int[] result = new int[digitwords.length];
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = Integer.parseInt(digitwords[i]);
}
return result;
```

The split there, is "split on all sequences that do not contain digits"

Java8 may help (with an added filter to remove empty values, not in the loop above), with:

```
return Arrays.stream(input.split("\\D+"))
       .filter(word -> !word.isEmpty())
       .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
       .toArray();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "short-circuit?" Isn't testing both `i == s.length() - 1` and `s.charAt(i) == ' '` the point? Is XOR really that uncommon? Thanks for the fantastic answer! It's exactly what I was looking for, I'm not too knowledgeable on using Regex, but I was sure there'd be a more eloquent way to do it with through that. The java 8 take is very well received.

Both these methods get letters otherwise in between letters, possibly desirable behavior. Again, awesome answer!

Comment: Splitting on `\D+` would obliterate negative signs. Splitting on whitespace is probably closer to the intended behaviour.

Comment: You can simplify the third line of your nice Java 8 example to: .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)

Comment: @chrispy - of course. It's a bad habit I got in to when I first started playing with Java8, and it's taking me a while to undo that.... in this case, I wrote that at my worst (but I still do it too often). It looks more natural to me for some reason to see the arguments passed to the function. Still, it's not right, you are.

Answer (score 4):

Well, @rolfl's is nearly identical to [mine](/a/75860/9357), and it's a lot simpler.

If you wanted to use your approach, here's how I would tweak it:

```
public static int[] getIntegers(String s) {
    ArrayList<Integer> helper = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++) {
        if (i == s.length() || s.charAt(i) == ' ') {    // End or delimiter
            try {
                helper.add(Integer.parseInt(sb.toString()));
            } catch (NumberFormatException discardNonIntegers) {
            }
            sb.setLength(0);
        } else {                                        // Possible number
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    int[] result = new int[helper.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (int n : helper) {
        result[i++] = n;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Changes to note:

- `int[] result` is declared where it is assigned.
- The loop terminates at a fictitious index just past the end of the string, to eliminate the special case `if (i == s.length() - 1) { sb.append(s.charAt(i)); }`
- `if (i == s.length() || s.charAt(i) == ' ')` is easier to understand than your XOR, I think.
- It is not necessary to check `if (sb.toString().length() > 0)`, as trying to parse an integer from an empty string would just throw an exception anyway.  If you *did* want to check, then `if (sb.length() > 0)` would work.
- You have to choose a name for `NumberFormatException`, so you might as well make it meaningful.
- I find if/else easier to understand than if-continue.  Due to the parallelism in formatting, it's easier to see that on each iteration of the loop we are either going to clear the buffer or append a character.
- Nobody *likes* boxed types.  You might as well unbox `n` slightly sooner.

Comment: Yeah, come to think of it the continue was no longer necessary(I tried something else before and it was a remnant), Thank you for the 'kindred to mine' approach! It's insightful.